# Send the Ctrl+Shift+NumAdd combination with Wscript.shell

Tags: vbscript

How to send the combination Ctrl+Shift+NumAdd with Wscript.shell?
By "NumAdd" I mean the "+" button on the numpad keyboard panel.

This way just doesn't work:

```
SendKeys("^+({+})")
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me on windows 10, but your code is incomplete ??

```
wscript.Sleep 3000
CreateObject("wscript.shell").SendKeys("^+({+})")
```

---

And this too works for Zooming :

```
wscript.Sleep 3000
CreateObject("wscript.shell").SendKeys "^({+})"
```

---

further reading about : [SendKeys Method](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/4b032417-ebda-4d30-88a4-2b56c24affdd.asp)

Comment: This has been done to death, do we really need yet another answer to this question? Why not flag it as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44332058/692942) to help the community and move on?

Comment: "^+({+})" - this code just doesn't work for me. I don't get any errors, but other apps don't receive this event as well. I use "wscript.shell" as a COM-server object from my app. When I use WinAPI SendInput function from my C++ code it works perfectly. Ok, I see that probably the problem is in something different.